# Navbar despocisionado y distorsionado

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap

Buen dia!

Mas que error tengo una consulta con navbar (aunque tambien se dan con otras situaciones). Estoy empezando un proyecto pero justamente me sucedio esto que no entiendo por que se da:

Mi codigo del default.Master es asi:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.master.cs" Inherits="GamblingWeb.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999xhtml>
<head runat="server">
<meta charset ="utf-8" />
<meta name ="viewport" content ="width=device-width, inital scale =1" />
<title>Mundialito Cash</title>
<!---jQuery minifield Script-->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!---Bootstrap Minifield Script-->
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!---CSS Minified -->
<link type ="text/css" rel ="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrap.css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<style type="text/css">
    .navtop {
        font-size: medium;
        text-align: center;
        background: #FF0000;
    }
    .firma {
        font-size: xx-small;
        text-align: center;
        background: #F78181;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class ="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
   <div classs ="container">
       <p class="navtop">Holis</p>
   </div>
 </nav>
<nav class ="navbar navbar-expand-md  fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="firma"> Gambling Site  <br> Copyright © 2018 Analisis de Sistemas I<br> IMR</p>
    </div>
</nav>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphDefault" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Agregue un webform con master page y no tengo absolutamente nada en este aspx de momento:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Default.Master"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LogIn.aspx.cs"    Inherits="GamblingWeb.LogIn" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphDefault" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

y compruebo con el design que se vea todo bien:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
pero al momento de ejecutarlo en el navegador termina viendose asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi duda es, por que se da estas situaciones y como corregirlas? se que no es algo complicado pero estoy aun aprendiendo y no encuentro una razon de por que se da o como corregirlo, hasta el momento la unica solucion que he encontrado es borrar y hacer todo de nuevo y funciona como deberia, pero se que no es asi.

Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es básicamente la definición de unos `<div class="container"></div>` innecesarios dentro de tu "header" y "footer" además de que asumes que como colocaste `navbar-expand-md` los elementos hijos de este `nav` van a heredar el `width:100%` del padre. Esto no es cierto ya que estamos hablando de un elemento `<p>` como hijo el cual posee `width` propio.

**Solución:** Eliminar los `<div class="container></div>"` de header y footer y además colocar en tus estilos predefinidos como `.navtop` y `.firma` la propiedad de `width:100%` así se ajustaran al ancho total que posee el padre de estos elementos (en este caso el padre es el propio `<navbar>`)

Te dejo un ejemplo con tu código al cual le hice los arreglos mencionados y ya se puede observar funcionando como deseas:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999xhtml>
<head runat="server">
<meta charset ="utf-8" />
<meta name ="viewport" content ="width=device-width, inital scale =1" />
<title>Mundialito Cash</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<style type="text/css">
    .navtop {
        font-size: medium;
        text-align: center;
        background: #FF0000;
        width:100%;
    }
    .firma {
        font-size: xx-small;
        text-align: center;
        background: #F78181;
        width:100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class ="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top">
       <p class="navtop">Holis</p>
 </nav>
<nav class ="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-bottom">
        <p class="firma"> Gambling Site  <br> Copyright © 2018 Analisis de Sistemas I<br> IMR</p>
</nav>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphDefault" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Observación:** No es común observar más de un elemento `<div class"container"></div>` ya que uno sólo basta para dar "formato" al sitio web y cumple la función de "wrapper" de todos los demás elementos presentes.

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!

Comment: Ah ya, te entiendo, muchas gracias por la aclaración!

Comment: De nada. Me alegra que ha sido útil